# Como fazer um Dump no MySQL para que o arquivo contenha a data?

Tags: mysql, backup, dump

Gostaria de fazer um Dump na minha base de dados MySQL, mas preciso que este Dump crie o arquivo.sql com a data em que foi feito o Dump, para que assim eu tenha guardado todos os backups anteriores por data.

Answer (score 1):

É só criar um shell script para efetuar o backup para você.

https://gist.github.com/juniorb2ss/3661141de3a0dbbeaa5b30c34d0062a7

Basicamente para pegar data basta usar: `/bin/date +%d-%m-%Y`

Restante só executar o dump e salvar o arquivo.

Comment: mas nao teria como alterar a propria linha de codigo do dump no mysql pra que ele crie o arquivo .sql com a data correta ? Por exemplo, eu uso o codigo do dump e o arquivo .sql criado ja vem com o nome dele sendo ( 26/04/2016) ?

Comment: Só colocar no nome do arquivo `$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql` na linha de comando.